# ActiveAdmin - how to delete ALL objects (not only those on current list page) (Rails ')

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

On my ruby on Rails app using [ActiveAdmin](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin), I wish to delete not only the 30 Users displayed but all the 456 users (that's an example of course).

When I select "select all' and then confirm deletion, it only deletes the 30 users visible on the current screen page.

I want to select ALL users (across all view pages, not only the one I currently see), and then manually deselect the first 4 users (or any I would manually pick on the current view page). So not really deleting ALL users. that's my problem.

How to customize ActiveAdmin to be able to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete some users from a list of all of them, I suggest you to write a [custom active admin action](http://activeadmin.info/docs/8-custom-actions.html). Minimize your markup, make it easy to render for browser and prepare for the worst. If you have 1 million records, there is no way it will work properly, there is no solution for that.

I suggest you to accept the fact that user will delete records by using search, probably and if you literally want to be able to delete **all** you can provide a custom button *delete all* that will do that for you.

The alternative is write a custom active admin action with a lot of javascript to provide pagination. It's still a lot of custom code, no generic solution provided.

Last alternative, you can disable pagination for that active admin page, but you may have a lot of problems loading the entire table every time

Comment: thanks you made me realize I was heading for the wrong direction. I don't need to delete 1 million records but even doing for 300, it was cumbersome to move from page to page. so i just changed pagination with config.per_page = 100. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this would work:

https://github.com/activeadmin-plugins/active_admin_scoped_collection_actions

Plugin for ActiveAdmin. Provides batch Update and Delete for scoped_collection (Filters + Scope) across all pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the default batch action to destroy/delete all the users like this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  batch_action :destroy do |ids|
    User.delete_all
    redirect_to collection_path, alert: "Deleted all the Users!"
  end
end
```

See [this](http://activeadmin.info/docs/9-batch-actions.html) for more information.

Comment: I want to select ALL users (across all view pages, not only the one I currently see), and then manuall deslect the first 4 users of the current page. so not really deleting ALL users. that's my problem/

Comment: I am not sure if you can have that kind of special type of customization. You can take a look at their codebase on github and how they implemented the batch action. https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/c24c92d4eef00eae464349b53328ea6dffa3cf21/lib/active_admin/batch_actions/resource_extension.rb
Also, you can try to write a custom action, but the way you want, I highly doubt if you can really achieve that even using a custom action.